# Retrofit2 - Percentage progressbar for request with long Base64 String in parameter

Tags: android, base64, retrofit2, rx-java2, android-progressbar

I have question... I want convert photo taken from device to Base64 String, insert to request body and post it on server via Retrofit 2. There is example of request body:

```
class MyRequestBody {

    private String name;
    private String description;
    private String photoBase64;
    ...
}
```

And there is example of API endpoint (`Single<>` is from RxJava, eventually I can use `Observable<>`):

```
@POST("upload")
Single<ApiResponse> uploadPhoto(@Body MyRequestBody myRequestBody);
```

My question is, if it's possible show in progressbar (in percent) how much data was already sent? And is this good solution or is better upload photo as file?

I want use on it Retrofit2, RxJava2 and RxAndroid.

Comment: see [this](https://medium.com/@PaulinaSadowska/display-progress-of-multipart-request-with-retrofit-and-rxjava-23a4a779e6ba) for example

Comment: Base64 comes with 33% size increase, it takes 4 chars to represent 3 bytes - I don't you really need that if you can control the server-side API design.